# easy family tree query

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

There is only one table.

Table name Family_tree.

Query all children for Nick. Nick can be also mother!

```
NAME                 ID    FATHER_ID    MOTHER_ID
--------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
Nick                  23         25        24
Jane                  10         27        26
Perl                  15         9         13
Katrin                50         6         12
Sandra                1          3          8
Demi                  2          3          8
Deimar                3          7          5
Gandalf               4          6          5
Bill                  5         10         23
Kelly                 6         22         43
Dolmar                7         11         20
```

Comment: Don't tag spam, just tag the RDBMS you are *really* using.

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far in order to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be like this:

```
select name, father_id, mother_id from family_tree 
  where father_id in 
(select id from family_tree
  where name = 'Nick')
or mother_id in 
 (select id from family_tree
  where name = 'Nick')
```

or if you need Nick only as a FATHER, then:

```
select name, father_id, mother_id from family_tree 
      where father_id in 
    (select id from family_tree
      where name = 'Nick')
```

Also, if you need only children , you don't need to use **connect by...prior** for grandchildren, grandgrandchildren, etc.

Comment: Bravo! This was exactly what I was searching for. Could you tell me how I could find grandchildren of nick in this case?

Answer (score 0):

If you're saying that Code = 3 means that Nick is that person's father:

If you only want to return the name:

```
SELECT Name FROM table WHERE code = 3
```

IF you want to return everything:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE code = 3
```

The '3' might have to be in single-quotes as I typed in this sentence, depending on the data type of the Code field + the particular SQL dialect.

EDIT: not  quite sure I understand the ask, but Rajee's answer might correct. You can join a table to itself with aliasing i.e. Family_Tree A, Family_Tree B

Another possibility would be a subquery. Because I'm not sure understand the ask, I don't know if this is what you're looking for but consider it an example of what a subquery would look like:

```
SELECT * FROM Family_Tree A WHERE FatherID = (SELECT ID From Family_Tree B WHERE Other Conditions = Other Conditions)
```

Something like that,  but same thing could probably be accomplished with my first answer or Rajee's answer with some more clarification.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what I am seeking for. Let me reshape my question. The table has more than 1000 rows so Nick is father for more than hundred so in this case in need some kind of recursion (connect by prior? sql query union? Secondly I need to recheck that nick is not for mother.

Comment: Well I'm not quite sure I understand the request or why it wouldn't work that way, but I think Rajee's answer might be correct. I can't respond to that thread, but  you can join a table to itself. You could also do a subquery, which I'll edit into my comments.

Answer (score 0):

select t1.name as child, t2.name as father
from table t1
join table t2
on t1.code = t2.father_id

This will give the following o/p

```
Child      Father
______________________________
Nick        fill from your tab
Calvin      fill from your tab
Sofia       Nick
```

Comment: I have only one table in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code -

```
SELECT 
  FROM Family_tree T1
  JOIN (SELECT ID, FATHER_ID
          FROM Family_tree
         UNION ALL
        SELECT ID, MOTHER_ID
          FROM Family_tree) T2 ON T1.ID = T2.FATHER_ID;
```